# Should object properties be declared in javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, language-theory

In a JS function, I'll be using an object `resultModel`, with two properties `idArray` and `nameArray`. What would be the proper way to declare this?

Currently I declare the object with `var resultModel` together with other variables at the top of the function, but the properties I simply start using by assigning them a value in a loop later in the function:

```
   resultModel.idArray.push(someValue[i][0]);
   resultModel.nameArray.push(someValue[i][1]);
```

Of course, I know that the `var` keyword is important for scoping, and as the "root" identifier is declared in the function I avoid any global tampering and this is all good.  But I have an expectation that the properties of the value really should also be declared somehow, for other reasons than scoping - memory allocation springs to mind, possibly type hinting via JSDoc comments, readability and sheer completeness of declaration.

So, my question is: should I declare such properties, and what would in that case be the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var resultModel = {
    idArray: [],
    nameArray: []
};
```

Assignment is considerably slower than just putting the properties on the object in the first place, so this is the best way to go.

Comment: `idArray: [], nameArray: []`

Comment: Wow, you're quick :-). The reason I don't do it at declaration time, is that the array is populated in a loop. I'm afraid declaring the variable in a loop will set off more than a few alarms.. Thank you anyway! (I'll edit my question to this effect).

Comment: Humbly you deleted your well-formulated answer, @abhitalks, you understood what I meant even before I edited the question. Indeed the code of this is now the same, but the text currently refers to the unedited version. Anyway, currently this is the best answer and amazingly quickly it was entered and edited. Thanks, people!

Answer (score 1):

The objects in javascript are allocated memory dynamically ,like in a linked list so i do not think we should concern about the memory allocation here.
For better readability you could initialise them with null value like abhitalks mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Put the property as a default value of same datatype .e.g for array -> Array(), for integers : 0 or -1 etc :

```
var resultModel = { "idArray": DEFAULT_VALUE , "nameArray" : DEFAULT_VALUE }
```